# Joomla multilingual site HTML tag attributes don't change after install k2 component 2.10.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, tags, multilingual

I found a problem in the **"System - K2"** plugin in **version 2.10.3**.
When the "System - K2" plugin is enabled, if the site is multilingual, the language attributes ("lang" and "dir") that appear on the HTML tags, don't change and only the default language attributes will be displayed.

I checked the **version 2.10.2** and everything is ok.

**Please note that it does not matter if you use the K2 component or not; just install K2 to see this issue.**

Please help and let me know what can I do?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Hesam.  Please take our [tour].  Please continue to research and work at this issue.  If you find a resolution yourself, you are welcome to post an educational answer to your own question.